# Django: TypeError when using max_decimal_places option of forms.DecimalField

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-1.8

I use Django version 1.8. I have a very simple form which I show below. It contains only a single field, a `DecimalField`. When I try to render any template in my whole project, I get

> #### TypeError at /whatever/
>
> __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_decimal_places'

Here's my complete **`forms.py`** file:

```
from django import forms

class BidForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.DecimalField(label="Bid amount", max_decimal_places=2)
```

If I delete the `max_decimal_places=2` kwarg that the error message seems to be whining about, my site renders fine and everything works great.

Why can't I seem to utilize `max_decimal_places`?

Complete stack trace follows.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://myproject.username.webfactional.com/myapp/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 3.4.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'localflavor',
 'myapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/myproject/myproject/urls.py" in <module>
  8.     url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/myproject/myapp/urls.py" in <module>
  2. from . import views
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/myproject/myapp/views.py" in <module>
  3. from .forms import BidForm
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/myproject/myapp/forms.py" in <module>
  3. class BidForm(forms.Form):
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/myproject/myapp/forms.py" in BidForm
  11.     amount = forms.DecimalField(label="Bid amount", max_decimal_places=2)
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/forms/fields.py" in __init__
  334.         super(DecimalField, self).__init__(max_value, min_value, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/username/webapps/myapplication/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.4-py3.4.egg/django/forms/fields.py" in __init__
  245.         super(IntegerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /myapp/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_decimal_places'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DecimalField) about the DecimalField

You can use `decimal_places`:

> The maximum number of decimal places permitted.

Comment: You should have linked to the [Form field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield) rather than the [Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield), but the point is taken.

Comment: I can't begin to imagine why the error message key is named `max_decimal_places` but the option itself is named `decimal_places`.